# passwd command to change the linux pc's password through php script shows permission denied

Tags: php

I Want to change linux pc's password through php script using "passwd" command, but somehow this is not working for me,, when m running the same command in terminal it is executing fine,
but when m running the same command in browser it shows "passwd : permission denied error".

I checked the permissions,they are 755 and ownership is "wwwrun".

and exec() function is not disabled in my php.ini file.

Please provide me the solution as i have to submit this application on monday.

Comment: Now we need to guess how exactly you're running the command?

Comment: You _do_ know about file permissions on a linux system? I am talking about the permissions of the password file, not of the php script...

Comment: $password= shell_exec("sudo -u root echo test2 | passwd --stdin testuser");                                                         here,test2 is the password for testuser.

Comment: how about `shell_exec("sudo -u root -c 'echo test2 | passwd --stdin testuser'");` ?

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code in the text ;) As well, I think that (1) you cannot `sudo` from PHP (`sudo` should ask for a root password right), (2) if you can, you should sudo `passwd` instead of `echo`, no?

Comment: permissions on password file is of "root" user.

Comment: @tohecz: "should ask for a root password right" --- not actually, `man sudoers` "you should sudo passwd instead of echo, no?" --- no. `passwd` accepts interactive input, and `echo` plays this role

Comment: @zerkms Since in your answer you `sudo` the whole expression, it shows that applying `sudo` on the `passwd` command seems necessary, no? That's what I was pointing to.

Comment: @zerkms :- thanks for help !! but this is not working... as this is working on linux terminal but when m running it through php script,it is showing permission denied error!

Comment: @user2101965: show the **exact** error. Any chance `selinux` is installed on your linux box?

Comment: @zerkms so you cannot `echo mypswabc | sudo -u root passwd --stdin testuser'` ?

Comment: @tohecz: I'm not sure about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program that has to be run as root is `passwd` and not `echo`:

```
echo mypswabc | sudo -u root passwd --stdin testuser
```

Comment: @user2101965 Then you might consider upvoting (the gray arrow on the right) and accepting the answer (the gray tick mark on the right) so show that the problem is resolved ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
shell_exec("sudo -u root -c 'echo test2 | passwd --stdin testuser'");
```

And your command doesn't work that you `sudo` only `echo` and what is after pipe is executed under current user credentials

Comment: :- with -c error is :- "sudo: illegal option `-c'"  and without -c error is :- "sudo: echo test4 | passwd --stdin testuser: command not found"

Comment: shell_exec("sudo -u root echo test4 | passwd --stdin testuser");       is working fine in linux terminal,,,but shows "passwd:permission denied" while executing through php script.

Comment: Now, if i need to change the password of my office's internal server's account through php script,what i need to do ??